# Angular 12 Multiple Layouts not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to use two layouts in the same project, the one with the route '/' goes perfect, but the '/admin' works properly until I reload, if I reload, I get some errors:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:44341/admin/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
dashboard:1 GET https://localhost:44341/admin/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
dashboard:1 GET https://localhost:44341/admin/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
dashboard:1 GET https://localhost:44341/admin/scripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
dashboard:1 GET https://localhost:44341/admin/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
dashboard:1 GET https://localhost:44341/admin/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
dashboard:1 GET https://localhost:44341/admin/styles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I have base href on my index.html, but it is like this:

```
<base href='/'>
  <app-root>
  </app-root>
```

and here is my admin and user layout, the user is the one that works properly

admin-layout.component.html ('/admin')

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./assets/img/apple-icon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/img/favicon.png" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>Admin</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY-HERE"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="adminStyles mat-typography">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar" data-color="red">
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="main-panel">
            <app-navbar></app-navbar>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

user-layout.component.html  ('/')

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
    <head>
        <base href='/'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>OCPM </title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/user/img/favicon.ico">
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>

   <body class="userStyles">
       
    <!-- Preloader Start -->
    <div id="preloader-active">
        <div class="preloader d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="preloader-inner position-relative">
                <div class="preloader-circle"></div>
                <div class="preloader-img pere-text">
                    <img src="./assets/user/img/logo/logo.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Preloader Start -->

    <header>
        <!-- Header Start -->
       <div class="header-area">
            <div class="main-header ">
                <div class="header-top top-bg d-none d-lg-block">
                   <div class="container-fluid">
                       <div class="col-xl-12">
                            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="header-info-left d-flex">
                                    <div class="flag">
                                        <img src="./assets/user/img/icon/header_icon.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-this">
                                        <form action="#">
                                            <div class="select-itms">
                                                <select name="select" id="select1">
                                                    <option value="">USA</option>
                                                    <option value="">SPN</option>
                                                    <option value="">CDA</option>
                                                    <option value="">USD</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="contact-now">     
                                        <li>+777 2345 7886</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="header-info-right">
                                   <ul>                                          
                                       <li><a href="login.html">My Account </a></li>
                                       <li><a href="product_list.html">Wish List  </a></li>
                                       <li><a href="cart.html">Shopping</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
               <div class="header-bottom  header-sticky">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <!-- Logo -->
                            <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-3">
                                <div class="logo">
                                  <a href="index.html"><img src="./assets/user/img/logo/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-5">
                                <!-- Main-menu -->
                                <div class="main-menu f-right d-none d-lg-block">
                                    <nav>                                                
                                        <ul id="navigation">                                                                                                                                     
                                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Catagori.html">Catagori</a></li>
                                            <li class="hot"><a href="#">Latest</a>
                                                <ul class="submenu">
                                                    <li><a href="product_list.html"> Product list</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="single-product.html"> Product Details</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                                                <ul class="submenu">
                                                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="single-blog.html">Blog Details</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
                                                <ul class="submenu">
                                                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="cart.html">Card</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="elements.html">Element</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="confirmation.html">Confirmation</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="cart.html">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="checkout.html">Product Checkout</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 fix-card">
                                <ul class="header-right f-right d-none d-lg-block d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <li class="d-none d-xl-block">
                                        <div class="form-box f-right ">
                                            <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search products">
                                            <div class="search-icon">
                                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                     </li>
                                    <li class=" d-none d-xl-block">
                                        <div class="favorit-items">
                                            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="shopping-card">
                                            <a href="cart.html"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                   <li class="d-none d-lg-block"> <a href="#" class="btn header-btn">Sign in</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Mobile Menu -->
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="mobile_menu d-block d-lg-none"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>
        <!-- Header End -->
    </header>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

   <footer>

       <!-- Footer Start-->
       <div class="footer-area footer-padding">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between">
                   <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                      <div class="single-footer-caption mb-50">
                        <div class="single-footer-caption mb-30">
                             <!-- logo -->
                            <div class="footer-logo">
                                <a href="index.html"><img src="./assets/user/img/logo/logo2_footer.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="footer-tittle">
                                <div class="footer-pera">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.</p>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5">
                       <div class="single-footer-caption mb-50">
                           <div class="footer-tittle">
                               <h4>Quick Links</h4>
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#"> Offers & Discounts</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#"> Get Coupon</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">  Contact Us</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-7">
                       <div class="single-footer-caption mb-50">
                           <div class="footer-tittle">
                               <h4>New Products</h4>
                               <ul>
                                   <li><a href="#">Woman Cloth</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Fashion Accessories</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#"> Man Accessories</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#"> Rubber made Toys</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-7">
                       <div class="single-footer-caption mb-50">
                           <div class="footer-tittle">
                               <h4>Support</h4>
                               <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Report a Payment Issue</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <!-- Footer bottom -->
               <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7">
                    <div class="footer-copy-right">
                        <p><!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
  Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="ti-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
  <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. --></p>                   </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5">
                    <div class="footer-copy-right f-right">
                        <!-- social -->
                        <div class="footer-social">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <!-- Footer End-->

   </footer>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to provide APP_BASE_HREF in component module, admin module and user module, but none worked... User works perfectly but with that, admin doesn't even loads...

I'm using two different styles for each layout

Edit:
Routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './account/register/register.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user/user.component';

const routes: Routes =[
  {
    path: 'admin',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }, {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
        {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => import('./layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module').then(m => m.AdminLayoutModule)
  }]},
  {
    path: 'register-login',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'index',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: First off, you don't need al that header/html/body content in your html files. The templates are loaded into `app-root` and assuming your `index.html` already has all that content then having all that extra content is incorrect. Additionally if you're trying to do routing for `/admin` then you'll need a `<router-outlet>` and in order to better assist we'd need to see your AppModule file.

Comment: You can solve your problem using child routes. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example